# JSDoc: Promise<Readonly<any>> vs. Promise<Readonly<*>>

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

I've paid attention that sometimes IDEA/WebStorm offers to use `Promise<Readonly<any>>` and sometimes `Promise<Readonly<*>>` when generating a JSDoc.

My questions:

1. Is there any difference between `<any>` and `<*>`?
2. Which one should I apply in case I want to specify a generic type of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html (and the [Closure Type System](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System#the-javascript-type-language) it references), `*` is what indicates that the variable can take on any type.
My guess is that you are using VS Code (which can treat JS files as TS, depending on your settings) and it supports [Typescript types in JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type) (and `any` would be the equivalent of `*` in Typescript)

Comment: Thanks, actually, I'm using IDEA/WebStorm.

Comment: I haven't used it before, but I would assume similar behavior if you have configured it to use Typescript